# Form Refreshing Problem in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form form A and from B . When user click button on form A , Form B will apperar but Form A is already open .User can set data in form B. When user click add Button in Form B ,the data will pass to form A and textbox in form A will
set data with pass data. I received passed data but Form A's textbox not fill with data.How could I do that ?

In Form B add button clik

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            EmployeeAddressEntity empAdd = new EmployeeAddressEntity();
            empAdd = AddEmployee();

            this.Close();
            NewEmployee emp = new NewEmployee();
            emp.FillAddressGrid(empAdd);    

        }
```

In Form A

```
public void FillAddressGrid(EmployeeAddressEntity emp)
        {
            txtAddressName.Text = emp.name;

            dgvAddress.Rows.Add(emp.type,emp.name,emp.homephone,emp.fax,emp.email,emp.address,emp.country_id);
            //int a = dgvAddress.Rows.Count;
            dgvAddress.EndEdit();
            dgvAddress.Refresh();
            dgvAddress.Parent.Refresh();

            this.Refresh();
        }
```

Comment: please provide some sample code. Are both forms running in under the same message loop? how are you passing the data ?

Comment: why not you paste your code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FormB, define a private field that stores the reference to FormA, and create a custom constructor to pass the reference.

```
public FormB(FormA form) {
    this.m_FormA = form;
} 

private FormA m_FormA;
```

When you show FormB from FormA, pass the reference.

```
using (FormB form = new FormB(this)) {
    form.Show();
}
```

When you are ready to update FormA, call your member function.

```
this.m_FormA.FillEmployeeGrid(empAdd);
```

Once you have all this working, you should not have a need to call Refresh() to update the UI unless something is going to be blocking the UI thread (in which you may want to do some asynchronous anyway).

Comment: I do refresh by Refresh() method but form not refresh.

Comment: Refresh() is a call that causes the form to invalidate its client area and redraw, it has nothing to do with updating your control's values. The reason you are not seeing your values update, is because you are not updating your instance of your form. You are creating a new instance of the form, that you are doing nothing with. If you implement the approach I provided (properly I might add), you do not need to call Refresh (which has no effect anyway for what you are trying to do), and you should get working results.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `NewEmployee emp = new NewEmployee();` in form b you are creating a reference to a NEW instance of FORM A (which is 'NewEmployee', right?) but you never actually SHOW this instance. When you invoke `emp.FillAddressGrid(empAdd);` you are acting on a hidden instance NOT the one which you can see.

When Your create an your instance of form B you need to pass a reference to form B like:

```
    FormB formB = new FormB();
    formB.Owner = this;
    fromB.show();
```

This will give you the ability to later call:

```
((NewEmployee)Owner).FillAddressGrid(empAdd);
```

from Form B.

Comment: ArgumentException was unhandeled. Top level control can not be added to a control.

Comment: It should be formB.Owner = this, because Parent would mean that FormB is a child control of FormA, and it is not.

Answer (score -1):

so u getting data from form B to form A,
Store recieved data in one variable and assign that variable to the textbox.
like,
textbox1.text=v.tostring();